# Duplicate key error on update query mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql

recently an upgrade to MySQL 8 was made. Within our database table, there is a column with a Unique constraint. When attempting to process the update query now we get

> error code 1062, duplicate key error for xxxx_key UNIQUE.

The prepared statement is along the lines of:

```
UPDATE td_id = ? WHERE td_id = ?
```

On some of the changes, the update command has run in the past, even if there is no real change. Now it seems to not run if a column has a unique constraint and you try to update that field and not make a change (keep the same value).

I also ran into 1062 while trying to re-enable the unique constraint on the field, as well as manually running the query to add a unique constraint.

We were not experiencing this issue prior to 8.0 update.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific here about the index definition. If `t_id` must be unique, you can't change that to a value already in the database. MySQL 8.0 may not be a factor here.

Comment: This does not seem to be an issue specific to MySQL 8, as the behaviour of unique constraints has not been changed. There's probably a different problem that just looks like it results from this. If your description is correct, a guess would be a trigger that does something that violates a (maybe different) unique key. Could you add the table description, an actual update statement and an actual error messge (that contains the key name and the value)? Otherwise we have no means to figure out where the problem might be and what you could investigate next.

Comment: Consider this scenario: (1) Find what needs to be updated (2) check if the new value violates any constraints, (3) Check if the update will have any actual side-effects, (4) do update if all steps were successful. It's possible older versions did 3 before 2, however if you are relying on something that is (as far as I can tell) undocumented, you're bound to run into problems. Perhaps doing `td_id=td_id` might change things but ideally you'd not run such an update at all.

Comment: I thank you all for your responses. Actually what was happening is NOT related to 8.0. I had the UNIQUE constraint on, and I did not consider the fact that the specific field should not be null. So what was happening is, the client approved a change on the admin interface which had 1 change with a empty value, and after that change, they attempted to make other changes with empty values and because one empty value now exists it is throwing the duplicate error